# Delete empty set{} in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

Implicitly defined functions in python are confusing me.

I have a dict

```
cluster={"coords":set([i,j]), "var2":x[i]<0.05 or x[j]<0.05, "var3":x[i]>0.95 or x[j]>0.95, "var4":v4}
```

[previously    dict={"var1":set([i,j]), "var2":x[i]<0.05 or x[j]<0.05, "var3":x[i]>0.95 or x[j]>0.95, "var4":v4}] changed variables to make it clear

So the next line of code reduces certain redundant `[i,j]` coords to an empty set so that `coords = {}`. I am having trouble then removing the "cluster" entries with `coords = {}`, so that only "cluster" elements with elements in `cluster` exist (basically filter out the empty ones by the value of coords).

I'm using python 2.7 so the dict list doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
dd = dict((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v != set())
```

This is a simple **dict comprehension** and filters out empty (*falsy*) values of `v`.

**Note:**

- Don't name variables `dict` shadowing the builtin `dict` type.
- This creates a new `dict` rather than modifying the existing `dict` instance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to delete items in a dictionary where the value is an empty set.

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    if v == set():
        del dict[k]
```

That should empty out all key value pairs with value of an empty set.

As said in the comments, `dict.items()` is only safe in Python 2.x. In 3.x, you can use `list(dict.items())`.

The reason being, it isn't safe to modify a dictionary while iterating through it. `items` will return a list of tuples in Python 2.x, which will remain static while you iterate through it. `items` in Python 3.x will keep checking `dict` through each iteration, thus iterating through an object that is getting modified. This is unsafe and unpredictable.

Comment: It isn't safe to modify a dictionary while iterating over it with `.items()` (depending on python version). Use `list(dict.items())` in python3.

Comment: In 2, yes. In 3 it is an iterator. It isn't clear what version the questioner is using, so it's worth mentioning that it's unsafe in 3.

Comment: Is the note I added accurate? I didn't know Python 3 would have a different generator implementation for `items`.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if some variable `x` is an empty set, you could use this:

```
if isinstance(x, set) and len(x) == 0:
    ...
```

I suggest using `list(dict.items())` (assuming Python 3).  `dict.items()`returns a *view* over the keys and values as tuples; this *view* will become modified when items are deleted from the `dict` even as you iterate through its items.  This can cause problems, so wrapping `list` around it will create a copy of this returned *view* and prevent these problems.  (A "view" is actually a *generator*, which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python))

```
for (key, value) in theDict.items():
    if isinstance(value, set) and len(value) == 0: # note len(value) only computed if value is a set, so no worries about calling len on something that has no __len__ defined.
        del theDict[key]
```

A note about conventions: the name `dict` is already used for the built-in Python function of that name, so consider using another variable name.